# How to filter the multiple selected values from an array and load it to other uitableview from a uibutton

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, json, uitableview

I have 2 UiTableviews in a UiViewController. My exact requirement is to get the selected values from tableview1 and loaded to the tableview2 by tapping the Add Button.

I done Following at the moment
1. loaded JSON Responses to tableview1 (loaded the responses from a filepath at the moment) and printed to a custom nib cell
2. I can get the selected values to a response as follows [image: Getting Selected Values as NSLOG responses]
Next
3. I want to print that values to *cell2 from the selected values. Please explain the next steps in details.

Here is the UI
[Main UI and Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXhQE.jpg)

Here are the codes from table loading to selections.

**Object - PSAData.h**

```
@interface PSAData : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *firstname;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *lastname;

- (void)loadWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict;

@end
```

**Object - PSAData.m**

```
@implementation PSAData

- (void)loadWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
    self.firstname=[dict objectForKey:@"firstname"];
    self.lastname=[dict objectForKey:@"lastname"];      
}
```

**table1 Viewcell - PSATableViewCell.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "PSAData.h"
#import "NetworkConnectivityClass.h"
@interface PSATableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic) NetworkConnectivityClass *networkConnectivityClassInstance;

-(void)loadWithData:(PSAData *)psaData;
@end
```

**table1 viewcell - PSATableViewCell.m**

```
@interface PSATableViewCell ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *firstnameLbl;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lastnameLbl;


@end

@implementation PSATableViewCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];


}

-(void)loadWithData:(PSAData *)psaData
{
    [self methodSetupText:psaData];
}

-(void)methodSetupText:(PSAData *)psaData
{
    self.firstnameLbl.text=psaData.firstname;
    self.lastnameLbl.text=psaData.lastname;

}
@end
```

**Main View Controller - PersonnelViewController**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


   //   NSMutableArray *selectedArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    tableView1.dataSource =self;
    tableView1.delegate=self;
    tableView2.dataSource=self;
    tableView2.delegate=self;

    //initializing arrays for get selected values
    self.selectedCells=[NSMutableArray array];
    self.selectedPSAData=[NSMutableArray array];

    //loading web resonse data
    self.loadedPSAData=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

     NetworkConnectivityClass *networkConnectivityClassInstance = [NetworkConnectivityClass new];

    __weak PersonnelViewController *weakVersionOfSelf=self;

  [networkConnectivityClassInstance methodReturnTableViewMessages:^(NSMutableArray *returnedArrayWithMessages)
   {
       weakVersionOfSelf.loadedPSAData=returnedArrayWithMessages;
       [weakVersionOfSelf.tableView1 reloadData];

   }];
    //register left side tableview cell (Assigned tableview1)
    [self.tableView1 registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"PSATableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"PSATableViewCell"];

}
```

//tableview Delegates

```
 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

        if(tableView ==self.tableView1)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        return 1; 
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

        if(tableView==self.tableView1)
        {

            return self.loadedPSAData.count;

        }
        return self.loadedPSAData.count;
    }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    //loading table data into cell tableview1 and tableview2
    static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"PSATableViewCell";

    PSATableViewCell *cell=[tableView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];


    if (cell==nil) {

        cell=[[PSATableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"PSATableViewCell"];
    }



    //tableview2 implementation
    static NSString *cellIdentifier2=@"PSSITableViewCell";

    PSSITableViewCell *cell2=[tableView2 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier2];

    if (cell2==nil) { 
        cell2=[[PSSITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"PSSITableViewCell"];
    } 
    cell.accessoryType = ([self isRowSelectedOnTableView:tableView1 atIndexPath:indexPath]) ? UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    if(tableView == self.tableView1)
    {
        [cell loadWithData:[self.loadedPSAData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]]; 
    }
    else if(tableView == self.tableView2)
    {
        [cell2 loadWithDataS2:[self.loadedPSAData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
        return cell2;
    }

    return cell;
    }
```

## pragma mark - multiple selection

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *psaData =[self.loadedPSAData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    PSATableViewCell *cell=[tableView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];


    NSString *sampleAH =[self.selectedPSAData description];

    if([self isRowSelectedOnTableView:tableView1 atIndexPath:indexPath])
    {
        [self.selectedCells removeObject:indexPath];
        [self.selectedPSAData removeObject:psaData];

        cell.accessoryType =UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    else{
        [self.selectedCells addObject:indexPath];
        [self.selectedPSAData addObject:psaData];

        cell.accessoryType =UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

    }

    NSLog(@"%@", self.selectedPSAData);


    sampleArrayholder.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", sampleAH];

}

-(BOOL)isRowSelectedOnTableView:(UITableView *)tableView atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return ([self.selectedCells containsObject:indexPath]) ? YES : NO;
}
```

**Finally NetworkConnectivity class - NetworkConnectivityClass.h **

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "WorksitenameList.h"

@interface NetworkConnectivityClass : NSObject

-(void)methodLogin:(NSString *)stringToLogin withUserName:(NSString *)stringUsername withPassword:(NSString *)stringPassword completion:(void(^)(NSDictionary *))completion;


-(void)methodReturnTableViewMessages:(void (^)(NSMutableArray *))completion;


-(NSURLSessionTaskState)methodCheckIfSessionIsRunning;

-(void)methodCancelNetworkRequest;
```

@end

**Finally NetworkConnectivity class - NetworkConnectivityClass.m **

```
-(void)methodReturnTableViewMessages:(void (^)(NSMutableArray *))completion
{
    dispatch_queue_t queueForJSON = dispatch_queue_create("queueForJSON", NULL);
    dispatch_async(queueForJSON, ^{
        NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"PSAData" ofType:@"json"];

        NSError *error = nil;

        NSData *rawData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath options:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe error:&error];

        id JSONData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:rawData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

        NSMutableArray *loadedPSAData = [NSMutableArray new];
        [loadedPSAData removeAllObjects];

        if([JSONData isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
        {
            NSArray *loadedArray=[JSONData objectForKey:@"records"];
            if([loadedArray isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
            {
              for(NSDictionary *psaDict in loadedArray)
              {
                  PSAData *psaData=[[PSAData alloc]init];
                  [psaData loadWithDictionary:psaDict];
                  [loadedPSAData addObject:psaData];
              }

            }
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            completion(loadedPSAData);
            NSLog(@"test: %@", loadedPSAData);
        });
    });

}
```

I Added All the required codes to have a look at it. Since I am relatively new to iOS Dev. Please Write a codes / instructions step by step clearly to save some time :).

**Please Note : At the moment I loaded the same tableview1 data to tableview2 *cell2 But I want here to load the selected values(Multiple Selection). from tableview1 loadedPSAData Array to load in table view to by tapping an Add Button. Finally sorry for my poor English ;) **

Comment: you want to display the selected values to next screen(tableview 2) ?.

Comment: Can you add the summary what you are trying to achieve? If you want to show the selected values in Next screen, You can Maintain an array of selected data by implying the logic of Indexpath of cells and then you can pass that array to your Next controller

Comment: @Signare Yes I want to display selected Values to the tableview2 but it's not in the next screen. it's in the same screen. (I will edit the post and add UI screen shots shortly).

Comment: @Wolverine I found few ways to pass the selected values from *selected array to next screen by using segues. But here we don't have navigation controller or segues to pass, because tableview2 is in the same UIViewController. Please help me.

Comment: Hi @Signare  I added Main UI and description by editing please have a look and support me ASAP.

Comment: Hi @Wolverine I added Main UI and description by editing please have a look and support me ASAP.

Comment: @FawazFaiz suggestion- when you click the add button, add all the selected values to array and reload the tableview2.

Comment: Make it simple and follow these steps. 1. Get your selected records in Array. No as you explained you are having table in Single controller, Then you can give them tag or accibilitylabel, And in DataSource methods of Tableview like, Number of Rows and cell for Row, You can check , table's tag/accibilitylabel, and pass your selected array there

Comment: @Wolverine I still not clear about this. Can you give me a sample code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose these 2 are your table outlet.

```
__weak IBOutlet UITableView * myTable1;
__weak IBOutlet UITableView * myTable2;
```

You set the Delegate and Data Source like below in your viewDidLoad

```
myTable1.delegate=self;
myTable1.dataSource=self;
myTable2.delegate=self;
myTable2.dataSource=self;
```

Now These are 2 Arrays

```
array1 ==> Which contain All Data
arraySelectedValues ==> Which contain you selected data
```

So you use this like below

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section   
{
    if(self.myTable1 == tableView) 
    {
        return [array1 count];        
    } else {
        return [arraySelectedValues count];
    }
}
```

As I review your Code, Your problem may be in CellForRow. Why to create 2 separate cells, when there is same CellIdentifier. You just need to change the Data.

You should create 2 cells **only** When Both Tableview are using **Diff-Diff tableviewcells.** In your case you are using same cell.

Try to modify the code like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"PSATableViewCell";

    PSATableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell==nil) {

        cell=[[PSATableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier];
    }

if(tableView == myTable1)
{
    [cell loadWithData:[array1 objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]]; 
}
else if(tableView == myTable2)
{
    [cell loadWithData:[arraySelectedValues objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
}
return cell;

}
```

**didSelectRowAtIndexPath** should look like :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 if(tableView == myTable1)
 {
  // Your code for highlighting
 } else {
  // This will be you myTable2 did select click.
 }    
}
```

**Just When ever you want to refresh the record, you should to Call ReloadData method For respective Tableviews.**

Hope you understand how you load the data in 2 Tableviews in Single ViewController.

Comment: Excellent Answer, It works! thanks @Wolverine. But When I select and Add Data to tableview2 it also passing some check marks as well. How to remove the check marks in tableview2 without tapping anything?

Comment: In "cellForRow", you can set "cell.accessoryType =UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;" for your tableview2.

Comment: Also apply the comparison of tableview on "didSelect" method when you are applying checkmark. It should be done only for Tableview1.