# How to send selected values of JSON Data to server from an uitableview by tapping a button

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

I implemented a method to load `JSON` Data to a `UITableView` and passed the multiple selected Array and loaded it in another tableview which is in the same `UITableView` [please refer this to understand my project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40298105/how-to-filter-the-multiple-selected-values-from-an-array-and-load-it-to-other-ui/40299282?noredirect=1#comment67861056_40299282).

What I want is to send the selected `JSON` data from Tableview2 to the server on tapping the confirm button.

I received the following url format as confirmed url (Only DNS name is edited because of privacy. Just take a look at the url format)

```
http://satests.com/srm/php/AJAXHandler.php?command={   "object": "BusinessEntity",   "method": "SetSQLView",   "params": {     "name": "InsertWPLog",     "records": [     {       "worksitepersonnelid": "35a0c9e1XX-161d-11e6-804c-005056bc570d",       "actiondate": "2016-10-06 13:24:35",       "actiontype": "SIGNIN"     }   ]   },   "security": {     "userID": 2   } }
```

A Java Developer from my team sent me a method to send this url in java as follows :

```
// button on click event
    String url = "http://satests.com/srm/php/AJAXHandler.php?command={\"object\": \"BusinessEntity\",\"method\":\"SetSQLView\",\"params\":{\"name\":\"InsertWPLog\",\"records\":[";
               String date = ""; //get system date
               for(String userID : userIds) {
                   url = url + "{\"worksitepersonnelid\":\"" + userID + "\",\"actiondate\": \""+date+"\",\"actiontype\": \"SIGNIN\"}";
               }
               url = url + "]},\"security\":{\"userID\": 2}}";

               // send request url
```

I don't understand anything from this but I wanted to send the above url format to the server.

Can Anyone explain the above method or post sample code for confirm button click event in OBjective-C.

Comment: is the Request POST or GET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look at JAVA code, I write some comments on it.

```
    // Build the request URL
    String url = "http://satests.com/srm/php/AJAXHandler.php?command={\"object\": \"BusinessEntity\",\"method\":\"SetSQLView\",\"params\":{\"name\":\"InsertWPLog\",\"records\":[";

    // Create the JSON Array for Records
    String date = ""; //get system date
               for(String userID : userIds) {
                   // Create JSON data for each Record and append it to the URL
                   url = url + "{\"worksitepersonnelid\":\"" + userID + "\",\"actiondate\": \""+date+"\",\"actiontype\": \"SIGNIN\"}";
               }
               url = url + "]},\"security\":{\"userID\": 2}}";
```

If you know about Objective-C, you can create the URL with above logic like this:

```
// Build the request URL
NSString *url = @"http://satests.com/srm/php/AJAXHandler.php?command={\"object\": \"BusinessEntity\",\"method\":\"SetSQLView\",\"params\":{\"name\":\"InsertWPLog\",\"records\":[";

// Create the JSON Array for Records
NSString *date = @""; //get system date
NSArray *userIds = @[]; // get data

for(NSString *userID in userIds) {
    // Create JSON data for each Record and append it to the URL
    url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ {\"worksitepersonnelid\":\"%@\",\"actiondate\": \"%@\",\"actiontype\": \"SIGNIN\"}", url, userID, date];
}
url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@]},\"security\":{\"userID\": 2}}",url];
NSLog(@"%@", url);
```

Comment: If you can re-write the code in objective-c and post it here. It will help me under the circumstances.

Comment: Please wait for me a minute.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Waiting for it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the tick.
You'll need to format the `date` string however you want it and change the request to `GET` if it's not a `POST` request.

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://satests.com/srm/php/AJAXHandler.php?command={\"object\": \"BusinessEntity\",\"method\":\"SetSQLView\",\"params\":{\"name\":\"InsertWPLog\",\"records\":[";
NSString *date; //I'm not sure how you want this formatted.

for (NSString *userID in userIds) {
    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"worksitepersonnelid\":\"%@\",\"actiondate\": \"%@\",\"actiontype\": \"SIGNIN\"}", userID, date]];
}
urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:@"]},\"security\":{\"userID\": 2}}"];


NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; //Change to 'GET' if the request is 'GET'.

NSURLSessionDownloadTask *task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] downloadTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSURL *location, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        //Sucessful
    }else {
        //Error
        NSLog(@"URL Session Error: %@", error);
    }
}];
[task resume];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I will try

Comment: what is the definition of the "userIds" ?

Comment: That will be the same as whatever `userIds` would be in your `Java` example.