# How to remove multiple selected items in an UITableview by tapping a button ? iOS Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, delete-row

I have a UITableview on an UITableview Controller. I loaded the table view with the data and stored the selected values in an array called "selectedPsaData" so far.

I wanted to remove multiple selected cells from tableview1 by tapping the remove button.

Following code is for my "didSelectRowAtIndexPath". I want a proper Remove/Delete function for -

```
(IBAction)removeBtntapped:(id)sender{
}
```

Please help me since I am relatively new to Objective-C.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *psaData =[self.loadedPSAData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    PSATableViewCell *cell=[tableView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];


    [self.tableView1 deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
  //  [self.tableView2 deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    if([self isRowSelectedOnTableView:tableView1 atIndexPath:indexPath])
    {
        [self.selectedCells removeObject:indexPath];
        [self.selectedPSAData removeObject:psaData];
        cell.accessoryType =UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    else{
        [self.selectedCells addObject:indexPath];
        [self.selectedPSAData addObject:psaData];

        cell.accessoryType =UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        [self.tableView1 performSelector:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2];  
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", self.selectedPSAData); //selected values are holding in this Array
}
```

Comment: Where do you store the original data? Is there a container called `psaData`?

Comment: Please add this to the Q.

Comment: @dirtydanee and Refer the following. I mentioned where I stored the psaData in another Question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40298105/how-to-filter-the-multiple-selected-values-from-an-array-and-load-it-to-other-ui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your current approach, you're going to get weird results while scrolling even if you get the 'remove' logic worked out (because the table view caches and reuses cells).

You should start by adding a `BOOL selected` property to your `PSAData` class.  Then your selection method can become:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    PSAData *psaData = [self.loadedPSAData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    if (psaData.selected) {
        [self.selectedPSAData removeObject:psaData];
        psaData.selected = NO;
    } else {
        [self.selectedPSAData addObject:psaData];
        psaData.selected = YES;
    }
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

To get the visual indicator, simply add a few lines inside `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

```
PSAData *psaData = [self.loadedPSAData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if (psaData.selected) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
} else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

Finally, removing items is a case of matching array elements.

```
- (void)removeSelected:(id)sender
{
    for (id object in self.selectedPSAData) {
        [self.loadedPSAData removeObject:object];
    }
    [self.selectedPSAData removeAllObjects];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: This is so true, Thanks @PhillipMills I will try this out.

Comment: Thanks tested and Working well :)

Answer (score 0):

You are keeping a reference on the selected PSA data, what is pretty good. So in your remove function, you should just remove the selected PSA data from the original PSA data array, and reload your `tableView`.

Your function should be something like the following:

```
    - (IBAction)removeBtntapped:(UIButton*)button {

        // Lets create a tmp container with the original data
        NSMutableArray *updatedLoadedPSAData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.loadedPSAData];

        // Lets iterate through the selected PSA data
        for (id selectedPSA in self.selectedPSAData) {
            // Remove the selected item from the tmp container
            [updatedLoadedPSAData removeObject:selectedPSA];
        }
        // Assign the tmp container to the original PSA data
        self.loadedPSAData = updatedLoadedPSAData;

        // Reload the tableView
        [self.tableView1 reloadData];
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Thanks for the solution but this one is not helping me. It's removing the last 2 records of the table, if we selected first 2 records.